# Pull headlines from Reddit

Tags: python, web-scraping

What's the best way to grab the top headlines on the front page of Reddit? Currently I'm using `BeautifulSoup4` to try to scrape them, but using the Reddit API seems like a viable option but I can't find anywhere in their documentation what URL to hit to request the top headlines. Something like `http://www.reddit.com/r/frontpage/top.json?limit=10` is my guess but this doesn't produce any of the headlines on the [frontpage](http://reddit.com).

**Python Scraper Method:** (not working)

```
def scrape(url):                                                     
    try:                                                                            
        req = urllib2.Request(url)                                                  
        conn =  urllib2.urlopen(req)                                                
        content = conn.read()

        soup = BeautifulSoup(content)  

        for link in soup.find_all('a'):                                                 
            print link                                    
    except urllib2.URLError, e:                                                     
        print 'Your HTTP error response code is: ', e
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Python Reddit API Wrapper](https://praw.readthedocs.org)?

Comment: According to the [API](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api#GET_top/) it would simply be `https://www.reddit.com/top.json`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following @jonrsharpe's comment, there is a python Reddit API client:

- [PRAW: The Python Reddit Api Wrapper](https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/v2.1.19/)

Use [`get_top()`](https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/v2.1.19/pages/code_overview.html#praw.__init__.UnauthenticatedReddit.get_top) to get the top headlines:

```
>>> import praw
>>> r = praw.Reddit(user_agent='my_cool_application')
>>> for item in r.get_top():
...     print item
... 
4901 :: I made a Redundant Clock.
4764 :: Elon Musk plans to launch 4,000 satellites to deliver high-speed Inte...
5144 :: Pipeline breach spills up 50,000 gallons of oil into the Yellowstone ...
4603 :: Avalanche Dog In Training
4564 :: TIL it is illegal in many countries to perform surgical procedures on...
...
```

There are also [`get_top_from_day()`](https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/v2.1.19/pages/code_overview.html#praw.objects.Subreddit.get_top_from_day), [`get_top_from_hour()`](https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/v2.1.19/pages/code_overview.html#praw.objects.Subreddit.get_top_from_hour) etc.

Comment: ah, these are from http://www.reddit.com/top/ not http://www.reddit.com. Using r.get_front_page() achieves the desired result.